# "Specks" on photos - possible to repair?

Tags: photos, hardware, iphone

I have several specks on the photos from my iPhone 5 64GB:

[image]

and here zoomed in

[image]

These are *not* on the lens as they are not blurred, so I assume they are on the sensor or faulty pixels on the sensor.

My question is if this is a repairable for a price which makes sense for an iPhone 5 64 GB. Any experiences?

Answer (score 1):

As far as iPhone replacement parts go, the usually the only ones that cost more than a few dollars are the digitizer assembly (touchscreen), logic board, battery, and (for the iPhone 5 and later) the rear case of the iPhone. Cameras usual cost less than $5.

Replacing the camera in the iPhone 5 is more complicated than it needs to be, but definitely possible. Here's the [iFixit guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+5+Rear-Facing+Camera+Replacement/10699).